# Why is the type defined twice when using floor() in C?

Tags: objective-c, c

I'm attempting to learn C/Objective-C. In this book I'm going through *(Objective-C Programming: The Big nerd Ranch Guide)* they set the type twice on this variable. Why? When I remove the `(unsigned int)` on the right side of the operator it still works the same.

```
unsigned int feet = (unsigned int)floor(rawFeet);
```

Comment: Don't tag with other languages just because they are somewhat related to the language you are trying to learn.

Comment: You only define the type once. The 2nd (unnecessary) one is a cast.

Comment: @Deduplicator I tagged it with C because in the book it says we are being taught C first before moving on to Objective-C, so I figured this was still part of C. Is it not?

Comment: @rmaddy you're saying it's unnecessary but why is it being used? What exactly is it doing when being used?

Comment: It's definitely not needed in this case. To learn what it is, read up on "casts" in C.

Comment: @rmaddy So is this particular code C or Objective-C? The C tag was removed.

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C. So it's both in this case.

Comment: @rmaddy: No subtle differences at all, like in the range of data-types? So, you wouldn't object to having each and every C question tagged objective-c?

Comment: @Deduplicator Why are you replying to me about this? What subtle difference are you talking about? Of course I would mind if every C question was tagged Objective-C. Not all C code is Objective-C code. You are either replying to the wrong person or you completely misread something I said.

Comment: @rmaddy: If not all C code is objective-c code, how can objective-c be a superset of c? You got me confused now. And tagging all C as objective-C would be a logical consequence of your previous statement, which led the OP to re-add C.

Comment: @Deduplicator You are taking this the wrong way. The OP's question was about learning C/Objective-C code. So both tags are valid in this case. But in general, even though all C code could also be considered Objective-C code, that in know way implies that all C code questions should be tagged Objective-C. I never said it should. Most C code is also valid C++ code. But no one is saying that all C code should also be tagged as C++. In this case, the OP is learning Objective-C but the posted code has no Objective-C specific syntax so it's also C code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It incorrect to say that the type is being defined twice. Defining a type means creating a new type. Here the type is being mentioned twice. On the left side it is being used to define a variable named `feet` of the type `unsigned int`. On the right side it is being used to cast the return value of `floor`, which returns a `double`, to an `unsigned int` - for assignment to the variable.

One side note: if you know rawFeet is positive which I would assume by the use of unsigned then calling floor is completely unnecessary.  Instead you can just cast rawFeet to unsigned int.

e.g.

```
double rawFeet = 24.6;
unsigned int feet = (unsigned int)rawFeet;
// feet now equals 24
```

Also, it was mentioned up in the comments that the cast is unnecessary. This may be true but a lot of compilers will rightly give you a warning about doing so.  In Visual C++ for example:

```
unsigned int feet = floor(rawFeet);

// warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
```

Comment: You don't even need the cast. The `double` will be implicitly cast to an `unsigned int` during the assignment.

Comment: @maddy. That depends on your compiler. msvc for one will give a warning and if you have warnings treated as errors then. well you know.

Comment: @jaket thank you, this definitely clarified its usage. But why is calling floor unnecessary when you're trying to just get the integer part and leave out the fractional part (as in 3.14). Will casting do this same thing?

Comment: @MichaelRader. Yes casting from a `double` to an `integer` will just truncate off anything after the decimal point. You have to be careful though because truncating a positive number is the same as `floor` but truncating a negative number is the same as `ceil`.

Comment: @maddy By providing the `(unsigned)` it lets both the compiler and reviews of the code know that the narrowing from `double` to `(unsigned)` was intentional.  To leave it out invites the question: "did code know what was going to happen?"